# Bootleg Grounds and a Light Switch

Tags: electrical

**ISSUE**
Recently started replacing the outlets in my home - found out that the outlets in my basement were bootleg grounded (neutral jumpered to the ground of the outlet). The circuit is run is in the following order from the source - Light Fixture, Outlet, Outlet, Switch/Outlet Combo. I'm assuming the reason as to why the outlets are bootleg grounded is that the source first goes to the light fixture and the bootleg grounds allowed for neutral to the fixture to be broken by the switch without killing power to the outlets.

**SOLUTION**
It seems to me that the only safe way to fix this issue would be to run a new feed from the switch to the fixture to provide switchable power for the fixture. New wiring order would look like this - Outlet, Outlet, Switch/Outlet Combo, Fixture. Any thoughts on my solution or alternative methods to correct this? I'd rather not run a new wire since there is no easy access to the ceiling or floor (bi-level house).

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box for the switch/outlet combo please?

Comment: No, what happened was they ran out of wires, so they re-tasked neutral to be a hot.  By the way when they do that, white must be used as the always-hot not the switched-hot, but if they violated Code one way I'm sure they did it other ways too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to fix it.

### Install a new cable run from switch to light.

This is pretty much what you propose.

### Replace the existing cable chain with /3 cable w/grnd.

Now, you assign colors as follows:

- White = neutral
- Black = always-hot
- Red = switched-hot

### Replace the last receptacle with a smart switch "master".

It then controls the light.  This switch is in an ungainly location, so you also install a smart switch "remote" in the desired switch location.  The remote talks to the master via either wireless, or powerline signaling.  I'm thinking of the Insteon family of products here.

Now the wire assignments are black=always-hot and white=neutral.

### Ditto, but keep the last recep also.

This would be done 2 ways.  One is by blowing out the receptacle box to a 2-gang box, so both recep and smart switch can lay alongside.

The other is by leaving it a receptacle, and using a smart-switch "faceless module" up in the lamp ceiling rose.  (or for that matter wiring the smart-switch "master" to be right next to the lamp) by adding an appropriate box there).

Comment: Wound up using a smart switch, thanks for the suggestion.